# Application like Gnome Hamster (a to-do task application with time tracking) but only using the terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line, to-do

I would like to have a time tracking application for tasks but using only the command line. Do anybody knows any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use [taskwarrior](http://taskwarrior.org/projects/show/taskwarrior) with journal feature.

Answer (score 1):

The only one I've heard about is [ctimetracker](http://go-beyond.org/?q=ctimetracker).

Answer (score 1):

Hamster has a built in shell called hamster-cli.
It is easy to use and it uses same db as the desktop version so changes are reflected in both places.

Comment: Indeed. But now I'm addicted to taskwarrior! :) Thanks anyway!